# [Angular2 + Facebook Graph API]: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, observable

I am trying to create a service to make calls to the Facebook Graph API in Angular 2.

Maybe, I am doing something wrong as I can't get it to work.

Error:
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Here is my code:

- Service

  ```
  import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
  import { Http } from '@angular/http';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/Rx';

  let URL = 'https://graph.facebook.com/me';

  @Injectable()
  export class FacebookService {

      constructor (private http:Http) {
          this.http = http;
      }

      getInfo(accessToken: string) {
          return this.http.get(URL + '?access_token=' + accessToken)
              .map(res => res.json())
              .catch(this.handleError);           
      }

      handleError(error) {
          console.error(error);
          return Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error');
      }
  }
  ```
- Component:

  ```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
  import { Routes, Router, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/router';
  import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
  import 'rxjs/Rx';

  import { AboutComponent } from './+about';
  import { HelpComponent } from './help';

  import { FacebookService } from './facebook.service';

  @Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'leaddockets-app',
    templateUrl: 'leaddockets.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['leaddockets.component.css'],
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES],
    providers: [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, FacebookService]
  })
  @Routes([
    {path: '/about', component: AboutComponent},
    {path: '/help', component: HelpComponent}
  ])
  export class LeaddocketsAppComponent implements OnInit {

    title = 'leaddockets works!';

    info:Observable < Array<Object> >;

    constructor(private fbService:FacebookService) {
      this.info = this.fbService.getInfo( facebook.accessToken );
    }

  }
  ```
- Template:

  ```
  <ul *ngFor="let obj of info | async">
    <li class="text">
      {{obj.$value}}
    </li>
  </ul>
  ```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: @A_Singh It's an observable, which should work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the data before you return it. My code is being returned at a promise but the concept it the same.

```
getFacebookFriends() {
   return this.http.get('https://graph.facebook.com/me/invitable_friends access_token=' + YOUR_TOKEN)
       .toPromise()
       .then(this.extractData);
}

private extractData(res) {
    let body = res.json();
    return body.data || {};
}
```